# Function toggle won't show div's inside the "toggled" div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm "required" to make a webpage:

> In a page I want a side menu and when clicking each option it shows in the right some content, but without "loading" another page (this would be the easier way, just making a page for each "option" and then just clicking in each button would lead me to that page with the content in the right).

I found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(IDS) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('pg').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { 
    if (sel[i].id != IDS) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  }
  var status = document.getElementById(IDS).style.display;
  if (status == 'block') { document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'none'; }
                    else { document.getElementById(IDS).style.display = 'block'; }
  return false;
}
</script>
```

I just added it to the side menu and when each part is clicked it shows what I want :

```
<div id="sidebar2">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="title">TEXT</h2>
                    <ul>
                          <li><a href="#" onclick="return toggle('pg0')">TEXT</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" onclick="return toggle('pg1')">TEXT2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
```

And in the content of each "option":

```
 <div id="pg">
  <div id="pg0" class="pg"> 
                        <h2 class="title">TEXT</h2>
                        <p><img src="images/test.png" alt=""/></p>
                        </div>

  <div id="pg1" class="pg">  
                        <h2 class="title">TEXT2</h2>
                        <p><img src="images/test2.png" alt=""/>HERE GOES THE DIV POPUP BUTTON</p>
                        </div>
```

I want a button to open a pop up image. It appears `toggle()` sets everything inside each `div` to `display:none;` and when I click only changes to block the outer part. But if I have a `div` inside, it remains hidden.

I've tried these two codes for the popup:

```
<div id="test">
<a href="#" class="JesterBox">
  <div id="image1"><img src="bg.jpg"></div>
  </a>

<a href="#image1">Image 1</a>
```

With the corresponding `JesterBox` definition in CSS:

```
.JesterBox div {

  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 75;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.JesterBox div:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 74;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.JesterBox div img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 77;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: all, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-out;
}

.JesterBox div:target { visibility: visible; }

.JesterBox div:target:before { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

.JesterBox div:target img {
  margin-left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And this other:

```
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">TEXT</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            TEXT TEXT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With its corresponding CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

I can't make it work. How could I make, for example, the 2nd option (the `div class="box"`) work inside the `div`?

```
<div id="pg1" class="pg">  
                            <h2 class="title">TEXT2</h2>
                            <p>
<div class="box">
        <a class="button" href="#popup1">TEXT</a>
    </div>

    <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
        <div class="popup">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
            <div class="content">
                TEXT TEXT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: for me it seems you need to use event.stopPropagation() in button click

Comment: is this what you looking for?? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8ekrvbem/  .. and please read a comment in function there